# create one jdbc onnection object but got too many connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I just created one JDBC connection object, and I got too many connection errors while inserting data into the database. I tried to find the cause in a different thread, but as far as I see, the "too many connections" error is caused by not closing the old connection and creating the new one.

```
public class LoadToDB {
    Connection conn;

    public LoadToDB(String url, String user, String password) {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

static final String insertCustomer = "INSERT INTO bank_customer (" +
            "CUSTOMER_ID, " +
            "CUSTOMER_NAME, " +
            "CUSTOMER_SURNAME, " +
            "CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, " +
            "CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE, " +
            "CUSTOMER_NATIONAL_ID, " +
            "CUSTOMER_BIRTH_DATE ) " +
            "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


public boolean insertCustomer(List<Customer> customerList) throws SQLException {
        int row = 0;
        for (Customer customer : customerList) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement insertCustomerStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertCustomer);
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(customer.getCustomerID()));
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(2, customer.getCustomerName());
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(3, customer.getCustomerSurname());
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(4, customer.getCustomerAddress());
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(5, customer.getCustomerZipCode());
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(6, String.valueOf(customer.getCustomerNationalID()));
                insertCustomerStatement.setString(7, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(customer.getCustomerBirthDate()));

                row += insertCustomerStatement.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (row > 0) {
            System.out.println(row + " Customers was inserted");
        }
                    conn.commit();
conn.close();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are closing connection only when customer list is not empty. If the customer list is empty, you are opening connection but not closing.

Comment: You aren't showing what happens if this method throws an `SQLException` on `commit()` or `close()`, or that that only one instance of this class can exist, and if that is the case it shouldn't be. In general `Connection` objects should be local variables closed by a `finally` block or a try-with-resources` block, not class members. That way they cannot survive the method they are created in.

Comment: juts one object of this class is created on the main method and SQLException  just has been thrown to the main method 
, Can we say if we have just one connection object we will have just one socket connection to the database?